# Cos'è "l'onda di piena"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te*, di Paola Mastrocola, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Si chiese anche, nel segreto dei suoi pensieri, se nella giornata ci si dovesse aspettare *l'onda di piena* e in quale misura sarebbe potuta essere, eventualmente, disastrosa: in poche parole, se i ponti della sua città rischiassero o meno di crollare.

Il personaggio femminile che ha questi pensieri è in quel momento contemplando un fiume in crescita dovuta alle intense piogge.
La mia domanda è: cosa significa "l'onda di piena"? Ho cercato questa espressione in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovata.

Comment: L'onda di piena è quella che si propaga con i fiumi ingrossati dalla pioggia. Lo trovi qui, per esempio: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argine

Comment: @egreg, la metti come risposta, ché finora mi sembra la più chiara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al di là dei significati tecnico-scientifici più rigorosi, vorrei spiegare quello che in linguaggio comune (o giornalistico) si intende come *onda di piena*.

A causa di forti piogge o di fenomeni che provocano irregolarità nel flusso di un fiume può succedere che una grande massa d'acqua si venga a trovare concentrata in uno spazio relativamente ristretto dell'alveo dello stesso, e continui a muoversi col flusso normale dell'acqua.

Essendo tanta acqua in poco spazio, non rimane piana sul fiume ma arriva ad un altezza molto superiore al livello normale. Questa massa d'acqua viene ad assomigliare all'onda che si forma in mare, pur essendo dovuta a fenomeni completamente diversi, da cui il suo nome.

Il punto più alto di questa onda può facilmente andare a scontrarsi con i ponti disposti lungo il fiume (pensati per il flusso normale del corso d'acqua) provocando i disastri che la scrittrice teme per la sua città.

Answer (score 1):

L'onda di piena descrive come si muove il punto a massima portata di un fiume, verso valle.

Per fare una analogia, immagina una pista in discesa (il fiume) con tante macchinine in fila (portata normale) e ad un certo punto metti in pista una  macchinina molto più alta delle altre (l'onda di piena), che procederà insieme alle altre lungo la pista. Se questa pista ha dei tunnel (come i ponti sul fiume del racconto) in cui normalmente passano le macchinine piccole, c'è il rischio che la macchinina alta non passi nel tunnel, così come c'è il rischio, nel racconto, che l'onda di piena abbia un impatto troppo forte sui ponti che deve attraversare e che quindi questi crollino.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Alain, e grazie mille della risposta!

Comment: Grazie del benvenuto, spero di essere stato utile!